# User queue and gamesessions in node.js

Tags: android, node.js

I'm making a 1 on 1 turn based game with Android clients and a node.js server. I want the users to be able to connect to a queue, waiting for some other player to connect with and when there's another player connecting, start a game session for the two players. How am I to hold such gaming sessions in the server? Is it just a simple temporary table in a database? Or is there some more efficient approach I should consider to increase performance?

Comment: is there a reason you don't want to use the mutiplayer, turn based game services from the Play Services API? https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/turnbasedMultiplayer

Comment: I'm more interested in learning how to make a decent network app. I haven't read that much into that service but it seems that it would simplify a lot of aspects too much.

Answer (score 0):

I suggested you using this platforms.

1. Redis Server. [this result of search for node.js & redis queue](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=redis%20queue&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#channel=fs&q=node.js%20redis%20queue)
2. [Rabbit MQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/)
3. https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-best-Message-Queueing-platform-for-nodeJS